# How to switch to generic auto redirect with delay

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, delay

I've inherited a site that calls a javascript on every page to prepend every external link with a link to an exit page. On exit.html, a function in the same script (confirmExit) extracts the original intended url, and that’s served up as a link on the page by ID `(<p>Continue to:<a href="" id="exitLink"></a></p>)`

Now, instead of the user having to click on exitLink, an automatic redirect with a delay is wanted. Something like "You will now be taken to exitLink in 10 seconds …"

I’ve seen the setTimeout approach, the `<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="seconds;URL=the-other-url">` approach, and even a form approach for achieving automatic redirects. Problem is, those seem intended for hard-coded, page-specific redirects. I haven’t been able to figure out how to adapt any of these to the js or the `exit.html` page to make them work. Sorry, I'm still low enough on the javascript learning curve that I can't seem to find the forest for the trees!

Any solution would be greatly appreciated! (Except php - I can't use that)

Here’s the javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    wrapExitLinks();
}
function wrapExitLinks() {
    var whiteList = "^gov^mil^";
    var exitURL = document.location.protocol + "//" + document.location.host + "/exit.html"; // Default exit is /exit.html from referring site
    var currentBaseURL = document.location.protocol + "//" + document.location.hostname + document.location.pathname;
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var linkDest;
    var linkTLD;
    var govTLD;
    /* Do not wrap links on intersitial exit page */
    if  (currentBaseURL != exitURL) {
        for (var i in links) {
            if (links[i].host) {
                linkTLD = links[i].hostname.substr(links[i].hostname.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);     // Extract top level domain from target link
                linkDest = links[i].href;
                if (whiteList.indexOf("^" + linkTLD + "^") == -1) {
                    linkDest = exitURL + "?url=" + encodeURIComponent(linkDest);
                    links[i].href = linkDest;
                }
            }   
        }
    } else {
        confirmExit();  
    }   
}
function confirmExit() {
    var queryString = decodeURIComponent(document.location.search.substr(1));
    var linkDest = queryString.substr(queryString.indexOf("url=")  + 4);
    var exitLink = document.getElementById("exitLink"); 
    /* Assume http:// if no protocol provided */
    if (linkDest.indexOf("://")  == -1) {
        linkDest = "http://" + linkDest;
    }
    exitLink.href = linkDest;
    exitLink.innerHTML = linkDest;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic script you need is simply:

```
setTimeout(function () { window.location = 'http://example.com'; }, 10000);
```

That's all. Work it into your script somewhere.